# Chrome 36 with Tridion 2011 or 2013

Tags: 2011, 2013, chrome

We’ve seen the following issues with Chrome 36 and Tridion 2011 and Tridion 2013:

- Component presentations are not displayed when viewing a page in the CME.
- Cannot create a new component.
- HTTP details are not shown in Publication Targets.

The symptoms may include the message "xlink' is an undeclared prefix."

We've applied all the latest service packs and hotfixes, but still see these issues.

If you see other issues with Chrome 36, please add them as comments here.

Comment: I've also noticed that when creating/editing components (in  CME) with lots of fields, the vertical scrolling on Chrome 36 doesn't work very well. I can only scroll down a little and therefore cannot see all the fields available.

Comment: Seems like the below error screen-shot belongs to this: ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/k3DWL.jpg) (80040356) Unable to retrieve converted schema Error in line 73 position 306. 'EndElement' 'ItemFieldDefinitionData' from namespace 'http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/R6' is not expected. Expecting element 'ExtensionXml | EmbeddedFields | EmbeddedSchema'. I have tried to create/modify a schema where I added one embedded schema field - As soon as I save or click on Source tab, it throws this error. Working fine in IE.

Comment: SDL have an open bug with Chromium here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=390879

Comment: All issues have been resolved in version 38 of Chrome browser. I did not apply any hotfixes in my SDL Tridion 2011 SP 1.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just to update to help everyone; Following hot fixes has been released to fix this issue:

- SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 HR2 - [CME_2011.1.2.88116](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=/downloads/hotfixes/SDL_Tridion_2011_SP1_2/index.aspx)
- SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 - [CME_2013.1.0.88115](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=/downloads/hotfixes/SDL_Tridion_2013_SP1/index.aspx)

  (SDLTridionWorld.com login required)

Comment: As far as we can see, chrome versions 37 and 38 still haven't fixed this, so I guess this hotfix will become "permanent".

Comment: looks like Chrome is heading towards IE path

Comment: Well, IE has not broken a fundamental part of XML parsing... so I'm not sure that comparison is fair towards Microsoft. Can't believe I'm defending MS instead of Google.

Comment: Just applied the hotfix on 2013 SP1 systems. Stuff works again!

Answer (score 17):

This appears to be due to a change (or defect) in how Chrome 36 handles the xlink namespace.

The Tridion vendor is working on a hotfix to adjust to the Chrome xlink handling - if I hear anything, I'll update here.

Comment: For the curious ones, this is the issue in question: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=390879, we're working double time to fix it ASAP.

Comment: Mac Firefox version 30 fails to load the CMS UI. We are not seeing the authentication pop-up.

Comment: not related to the original question, but don't see a way to delete my comment from this thread. Mac Firefox version 30 fails to load the CMS UI. We are not seeing the authentication pop-up. This is because NTLMv1 has been disabled by default https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/30/Site_Compatibility#Security

Comment: That sounds like a different issue S.T.. You might want to open a separate question for it and provide the answer yourself.

Comment: Officially, FF on Mac is not supported (only Safari), which means it may not have been tested. And indeed it should be a different question rather than a comment here.

Answer (score 3):

If your system hasn't already "upgraded" to Chrome 36, you can stop automatic Google updates by following the instructions [here](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/turning-off-auto-updates).