# Error 'xlink' is an undeclared prefix on SDL Tridion GUI

Tags: cme

When I am creating any thing on SDL Tridion using GUI, I am getting the following error

"'xlink' is an undeclared prefix. Line 1, position 179".

This was not showing up earlier but all of a sudden it has started to show up

Comment: If you're using Chrome 36, please see this: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/7247/chrome-36-with-tridion-2011-or-2013 and this: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=390879. For the time being, please use a different browser.

Comment: So basically this is a Chrome Bug and not a Tridion. In future to avoid such issues, keep automatic update of your browser (specifically Chrome) to Off.

Comment: Thanks @Nuno,@Pankaj My issue is resolved when I run the SDL Tridion on Mozilla Firefox

Comment: We will have a hotfix for Chrome soon, hopefully later this week (working around the Chrome bug, not really the best usage of our dev time... I guess when you're Google you can do anything.)

Comment: @NunoLinhares when your browser is popular enough that other companies will work around your bugs you can do anything ;)

Comment: @Nuno,@Pankaj i want to ask one thing more that many time when i open the schema in SDL TRIDION  GUI and click on design button then many time i am getting system error in retrieve data it is coming because i am using Chrome 36 or due to other reason.