# 2013 SP1 Experience Manager Update Preview get hibernate.StaleStateException error

Tags: 2013

2013 SP1 Experience Manager Update Preview get hibernate.StaleStateException error, all JARs/DLLs version for 2013 SP1 are correct.

cd_core Log:

2014-08-15 15:33:51,817 ERROR SessionWrapperFactory - Exception while cleaning-up session data
com.tridion.broker.StorageException: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPABaseDAO.remove(JPABaseDAO.java:157) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPAItemDAO.remove(JPAItemDAO.java:246) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.persistence.session.SessionWrapperFactory.deleteItemMeta(SessionWrapperFactory.java:184) ~[cd_session.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.persistence.session.SessionWrapperFactory.cleanupSessionData(SessionWrapperFactory.java:160) ~[cd_session.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.session.SessionManagerImpl.expireSession(SessionManagerImpl.java:414) [cd_session.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.session.SessionManagerImpl.performCleanup(SessionManagerImpl.java:230) [cd_session.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.persistence.session.SessionsCleanerMonitor.run(SessionsCleanerMonitor.java:52) [cd_session.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:90) ~[hibernate-entitymanager.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPABaseDAO.remove(JPABaseDAO.java:148) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.wrapStaleStateException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1402) ~[hibernate-entitymanager.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1308) ~[hibernate-entitymanager.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1289) ~[hibernate-entitymanager.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:78) ~[hibernate-entitymanager.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:81) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:73) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:57) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3124) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3327) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:91) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:272) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:264) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:191) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1081) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:315) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:73) ~[hibernate-entitymanager.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    ... 8 common frames omitted

Comment: this issue happens when click on "Update Preview" button on experience manager. checked all JARs or DLLs, web.config on CD, cannot find the right path to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to figure out your issues, but this is possibly the same question here:

[Database exception on Session Broker database for Experience Manager on Tridion 2013 SP1](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/7303/database-exception-on-session-broker-database-for-experience-manager-on-tridion)

I'd check off the steps asked in the question then come back if you've still got an issue with a more specific question.

Comment: this posting is very close to mine with only difference is: org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

Comment: Exception type: ConfigurationException 
    Exception message: <JavaException>
  <Type>com/tridion/configuration/ConfigurationException</Type>
  <Message><![CDATA[Ambient Data Framework configuration was not properly initialized.]]></Message>
  <StackTrace><![CDATA[com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: Ambient Data Framework configuration was not properly initialized.
   at Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.Runtime.AmbientRuntime.Setup()

Comment: hi lucas, my point is still the same, there's a number of things you need to check, other than just the library files suchs as configs, connection settings etc

Comment: checked: 
1. Wrappers YES
2. cd_storage_conf.xml YES
3. AmbientData HttpModule YES
4. PreviewContentModule YES
5. cd_ambient_conf.xml YES
6. OData Webservice YES
7. cd_ambient_conf YES