# Tridion 2011 GUI not showing warning and error messages

Tags: cme, 2011-sp1

I have a strange issue on the Tridion 2011 CME where it won't show the error/warning messages and prompts tot the Tridion user.
Forgetting to fill in a mandatory field, copying an item in a folder, etc... all results in and the never ending message "saving/Pasting item".

I can see the warning in the event viewer when I log into the server. I cannot find the process or issue that is responsible for relaying those messages to the GUI.

Comment: What browser is used? Does context menus work?

Comment: Context menu's work fine. It has been tested in different browsers to exclude that option.

Comment: Have you checked the developer console of your browser to see if you are getting JavaScript errors? Especially when it comes to mandatory error messages, they're typically handled entirely on the client -- so if they don't show up, something is broken (maybe some extensions you have installed?)

Comment: I had not checked that before, but I do not get any messages when looking at the developer console. (_On another system that is is working properly I actually see the error appear in the console, which is a good thing._)

Comment: Hmm, maybe also check browser versions. I had Chrome *working* despite a [recent bug](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/7247/46) because I hadn't closed it yet. So auto-updated Chrome versions were broken by mine was okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all the replies.

We ended up installing Tridion 2011 on a new windows server. The issue was most likely caused by some legacy code, or DLL's. The system had been in use for many years and had seen 3 upgrades (From R5.2 tot 2011).

Answer (score 2):

I doubt it is something related to the health of your Tridion Database. Can you confirm if you have been doing the DB maintenance as specified in the Tridion Maintenance Manual?
Also, I would like to suggest to check the performance of the DB server as well as the CMS server in terms of CPU and Memory utilization.

Further you may try by restarting all all Tridion Services, COM+ on CMS and the SQL Server services on the DB server.