# Unable to upload a text file using Load From Disk

Tags: multimedia

I am trying to upload a text file using Load From Disk.  Right now I am just doing a test file but ultimately need to use this to upload the robots.txt file to our site.  (Our SEO team wants an easy way to modify and publish this file in between our web deployments which happen about every 6 weeks)

The steps I have taken are.

1. Create
2. New Multimedia Component
3. Name -> TestText
4. Schema -> Default Multimedia Schema
5. Multimedia Type -> Plain Text
6. Resource Type -> Uploaded
7. Upload text file from disk (My    text file is just a simple one line file.)
8. Save ->  Error message    'XLink' is an undeclared prefix. Line 1 Position 150.

Any help would be appreciated as I can't find any documentation or information on doing this.

Thanks.

Rhonda

Comment: Are you able to upload other Multimedia Components? There was a Chrome bug which prevented uploading files. What version of Tridion are you using? I suspect this may be your issue http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/7247/chrome-36-with-tridion-2011-or-2013

Comment: This is definitely the chrome bug - you'll have this error with any component. Have your sys admins deploy hotfix CME_2013.1.0.88115

Comment: Thanks,  I have passed this information to our sys admins to deploye the hotfix.

Comment: @NunoLinhares, please convert your comment to an answer so that it can be marked "correct" for completion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The behavior you're describing is consistent with the bug introduced by Chrome 36 (and fixed in the upcoming Chrome 38). SDL has issued hotfix CME_2013.1.0.88115 to address it, ask your system administrator to deploy this fix and the problem should go away.

Alternatively you can use a different browser while waiting for the hotfix.