# Issues with Chrome 42 opening inherited components

Tags: 2013, 2013-sp1, chrome

Is anyone else experiencing issues with Chrome 42 upgrade and Tridion?

I have 2 users who upgraded to Chrome 42 and are now getting the "Failed to open a window. If you have a pop up blocker enabled, disable it." message when trying to open an inherited component. Opening the at the source / local publication level opens fine.

We are using SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1.

I have tried to submit a ticket at on the support portal but am getting a 504 Gateway time-out error. Perhaps everyone is at SDL Innovate this week.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As promised, I have applied Hotfix CME_2013.1.1.88718 to our environments and it has fixed the Chrome 42 issue on all of them.

Hotfix is available from SDL support or https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/hotfixes/SDL_Tridion_2013_SP1_HR1/index.aspx

Good luck to everyone else who had this problem and thank you for the responses.

Answer (score 4):

Yes - I have experienced this problem, and have also heard reports from other people of the same thing. I've been working around it by simply using a different browser. 
It's starting to look like Chrome updates are a source of risk. Do you remember the problems with [Chrome 36](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/7247/129)? That problem was addressed in the short term by a Tridion hotfix, and then eventually by a fix in Chrome. So it would make sense to report this via Tridion support.

Comment: And let's hope the portal comes back up soon.

Comment: Hi Dominic,
Thanks for your response. I do remember the Chrome 36 issues vividly. I'm glad it's not just us then.

I have managed to get a support ticket raised and will update this thread when I get a response.

Comment: We are also facing the same issue. Hope to see quick resolution on this as the impact is widespread. Can this be added to Tridion KB in known issues as it helps in keeping watch on issues which impacts us and equips us to better communicate with our users when they face these issues?

Comment: Another one suffering this issue.

Comment: Rest assured that SDL is looking into it. Hopefully we'll have a hotfix for you soon.

Comment: Hi Vipin and Raul Escudero, can you also confirm what versions of Tridion you have installed?

Comment: We received notification of the Hotfix too. I will be applying the hotfix on Monday and will let you all know how we get on.

Comment: Hi, Will this hotfix be released for 2013 SP1 as well? I see that this is included only in the 2013 SP1 HR1 downloads. I'm a little concerned about applying the fix that's not been specifically released for 2013 SP1. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The hotfix for this issue is available on Tridion World on the downloads page for 2013 SP1 HR1 - CME_2013.1.1.88718:
https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/hotfixes/SDL_Tridion_2013_SP1_HR1/index.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Although the hotfix - CME_2013.1.1.88718 has been released for SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR#1; but I can confirm that this will also work for SDL Tridion SP1 as well. Apply the hotfix on my SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 environment and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

SDL sent CME_2013.1.1.88718 today, that they said would resolve this issue.